# Issue storing weather data from API using react and JSON-sever

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I would like the search the `/weather` and return the weather conditions. To ultimately render the weather to my app

With my code I am targeting the users input for postcode, once I have the longitude and latitude from the `/location` API I am then making a `/GET` request to the `/weather` API

With my code below I am unable to setWeather with weather conditions. I believe it might to do with waiting for the data?

Any help is appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "../App.css";


export default function PostcodeInputForm() {
  const [postcode, setPostcodeValue] = React.useState("");
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = React.useState("");
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = React.useState("");
  const [weather, setWeather] = React.useState([]);

  let roundLongTwoDecimals = Number(longitude).toFixed(2);
  let roundLatTwoDecimals = Number(latitude).toFixed(2);

  // console.logs for debugging. If code makes it to production all logs would be removed



  const storePostcode = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setPostcodeValue(event.target.value);
  };

  // Error handling: If there isn't any response from the server return an error

  const checkResponse = (response) => {
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Network error: ${response.status}`);
    return response.json();
  };

  const getLocations = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3030/locations")
      .then(checkResponse)
      .then((result) => {
        result.map((object) => {
          if (object.postcode == postcode) {
            setLongitude(object.longitude);
            setLatitude(object.latitude);
          }
        });
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocations();
  }, []);

  

  const getWeather = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3030/weather")
      .then(checkResponse)
      .then((result) => {
        result.map((data) => {
          // console.log(data.coord.lat);
          // console.log(roundLongTwoDecimals);
          console.log(data.weather[0].description);

          if (
            data.coord.lon == roundLongTwoDecimals &&
            data.coord.lat == roundLatTwoDecimals
          ) {

            // ** Issue ** Not storing the weather data
            setWeather(data.weather[0].description);
          }
        });
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();
  }, []);

  

  console.log(weather);

  return (
    <main>
      <form onSubmit={getLocations()}>
        <input
          placeholder="Enter your postcode... "
          type="text"
          className="postcode-search-bar"
          id="postcode"
          name="postcode"
          required
          value={postcode}
          onChange={storePostcode}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}
```

JSON-server mock api

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": 145,
      "postcode": "E8 3DB",
      "eastings": 533638,
      "northings": 184527,
      "country": "England",
      "nhs_ha": "London",
      "longitude": -0.074253,
      "latitude": 51.543824
    },
    {
      "id": 233,
      "postcode": "M5 3AA",
      "eastings": 381457,
      "northings": 397673,
      "country": "England",
      "nhs_ha": "North West",
      "longitude": -2.280845,
      "latitude": 53.475455
    },
    {
      "id": 314,
      "postcode": "B9 4BB",
      "eastings": 408295,
      "northings": 286771,
      "country": "England",
      "nhs_ha": "West Midlands",
      "longitude": -1.879291,
      "latitude": 52.478819
    },
    {
      "id": 144,
      "postcode": "EX1 3AB",
      "eastings": 294187,
      "northings": 93121,
      "country": "England",
      "nhs_ha": "South West",
      "longitude": -3.500568,
      "latitude": 50.728041
    }
  ],
  "weather": [
    {
      "id":2643743,
      "coord": {"lon":-0.07,"lat":51.54},
      "weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],
      "base":"stations",
      "main":{"temp":289.28,"feels_like":285.24,"temp_min":288.71,"temp_max":290.15,"pressure":1016,"humidity":77},
      "visibility":10000,
      "wind":{"speed":6.7,"deg":230},
      "clouds":{"all":90},
      "dt":1604060381,
      "sys":{"type":1,"id":1414,"country":"GB","sunrise":1604040660,"sunset":1604075829},
      "timezone":0,
      "name":"London"
    },
    {
      "id":2643123,
      "coord": {"lon":-2.28,"lat":53.48},
      "weather":[{"id": 500,"main": "Rain","description": "light rain","icon": "10n"}],
      "base":"stations",
      "main":{"temp":285.76,"feels_like":284.05,"temp_min":285.15,"temp_max":285.93,"pressure":1012,"humidity":100},
      "visibility":10000,
      "wind":{"speed":3.6,"deg":270},
      "clouds":{"all":90},
      "dt":1604060843,
      "sys":{"type":1,"id":1379,"country":"GB","sunrise":1604041483,"sunset":1604076019},
      "timezone":0,
      "name":"Manchester"
    },
    {
      "id":3402721,
      "coord":{"lon":-1.88,"lat":52.48},
      "weather":[{"id": 800,"main": "Clear","description": "clear sky","icon": "01d"}],
      "base":"stations",
      "main":{"temp":302.15,"feels_like":304.15,"temp_min":302.15,"temp_max":302.15,"pressure":1014,"humidity":70},
      "visibility":10000,
      "wind":{"speed":4.6,"deg":90,"gust":11.3},
      "clouds":{"all":40},
      "dt":1604061309,
      "sys":{"type":1,"id":8426,"country":"GB","sunrise":1604044422,"sunset":1604088963},
      "timezone":0,
      "name":"Birmingham"
    },
    {
      "id":2015306,
      "coord":{"lon":-3.50,"lat":50.73},
      "weather":[{"id":602,"main":"Snow","description":"heavy snow","icon":"13d"}],
      "base":"stations",
      "main":{"temp":262.28,"feels_like":257.3,"temp_min":262.28,"temp_max":262.28,"pressure":1028,"humidity":96,"sea_level":1028,"grnd_level":1023},
      "visibility":628,
      "wind":{"speed":2.61,"deg":331},
      "clouds":{"all":100},
      "dt":1604061539,
      "sys":{"country":"GB","sunrise":1604016259,"sunset":1604038312},
      "timezone":32400,
      "name":"Exeter"
    }
  ]
}
```

My app.js

```
import "./App.css";
import PostcodeInputForm from "./components/PostcodeInputForm";

function App() {
  let date = new Date().toDateString();
  date = date.slice(3, 15);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <main>
        <div className="search">
          <h1>Local Weather</h1>
          <PostcodeInputForm />
        </div>
        <div className="weather-location-container">
          <p className="location">London</p>
          <div className="date">{date}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="weather-container">
          <div className="temp">8°c</div>
          <div className="weather">Cloudy</div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Try moving your ```getWeather``` function to inside the ```useEffect``` hook. Also ```data.coord``` doesn't exist. ```coord``` only exists inside ```data.weather[0]```.

Comment: Hi Kyle thanks for the input  when I ```console.log(data.coord.lat) ```  receive a correct  latitude value. Is there any other way I should be comparing the latitude?

Comment: Also do you mean adding the ```getWeather``` function inside ```[ ]``` of the useEffect hook?